# SWIFT Pass data to variable into cell.swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm facing a problem on my code.
I've got a tableview with custom cells
At this time, everything works fine.

I would like to pass an array (or an id or whatever) to my cell to make some stuff in it.

I've create my var in my cell.swift file
In my code I'm giving my var a value in my tableview cellForRowAt but when I want to print my data, nothing appends I've 0.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "question_cell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell                            
    cell.id = 12
}
```

and in my cell file

```
var id = Int()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    print(id)
}
```

When I print, I've got the following result : 0

I would like to have : 12

Thank you if you can help me to fix my last problem on this project. Thanks

Comment: Try to print `id `'s value after `dequeueReusableCell `. It means don't print the value in `awakeFromNib ` method.

Comment: The problem is that I'm going to use the passed data (it will be an array later) to generate my radio list created in the current cell

so I need to get data at this moment precisely

Is there any other method to send data in the awakeFromNib ?

Comment: 1. Create a method(say `abc()`) in the tableview cell class. 2. Pass the necessary value in that method. 3. Call this method after `dequeueReusableCell` line. 4. In `abc()`, handle the input data accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

printing in awake from nib is not a good idea. Because that will be called when the cell is initiated. 
Instead do this in you cell file:

```
var id: Int = 0 { 
   didSet {
       print(id) // and also run any additional code here
   }
}
```

So whenever you set a value to that cell the DidSet is being called.

Comment: If i have two var the want to do something when both of them not empty.

Answer (score 0):

`awakeFromNib()` is called when `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "question_cell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell`, the `id` isn't set yet, so it returns `zero`. This may be solved by

```
var id: Int = 0 { 
   didSet {
       print(id) 
   }
}
```

or write a method that will set method, a kinda childish working and **not recommended**

```
func setId(id : Int) {
   self.id = id 
   print(id)
}
```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "question_cell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionsCell                            
    cell.setId(id : 12)
    return cell
}
```